# after_build runs 2 times in FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot, rspec2

There is my model:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create do
    pp id
    track_activity
  end
end
```

This is my factoty:

```
 factory :user do 
    email {Factory.next :email}
    after_build do |user|
      user.profile_attributes = {name: 'why'}
    end
  end
```

The id prints 2 times with the follow code in spec:

```
expect do
  user = create :user
end.to change(Activity, :count).by 1
```

Comment: Please share your entire spec.